# Different XSLT processing result compared with xsltproc

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, libxml2, libxslt

I'm doing XSLT processing with libxslt(plus libxml2, libexslt).
First, I did my XSLT processing with `xsltproc` using an XML input file like below and using MS Office's XSL file(APASixthEditionOfficeOnline.xsl). You can see the XML output like below.

**XML input (input.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<b:StyleNameLocalized xmlns:b="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography">
    <b:Lcid>1042</b:Lcid>
</b:StyleNameLocalized>`
```

**XSL stylesheet (APASixthEditionOfficeOnline.xsl)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:b="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="us-ascii"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="b:StyleNameLocalized">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="b:StyleNameLocalized/b:Lcid='1042'">
              <xsl:text>APA</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>             
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML output by `xsltproc`**

- I wrote the below code in the command line.

  > xsltproc APASixthEditionOfficeOnline.xsl input.xml > output.xml
- And I got a text in output.xml 
   
  APA

---

Meanwhile, I tried to make my own xsltproc by implementing the functions of libxml2 and libxslt.

I used the same APASixthEditionOfficeOnline.xsl file, however didn't parsed the input.xml but generated XmlDocPtr in the code. Below is my code.

**My Code**

```
const xmlChar* stylesheetfile = (const xmlChar*)"APASixthEditionOfficeOnline.xsl";
xsltStylesheetPtr style = xsltParseStylesheetFile(xslfile);
xmlDocPtr doc = xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST "1.0");
xmlNodePtr root_node = xmlNewNode(NULL, BAD_CAST "b:StyleNameLocalized");
xmlNsPtr ns =
        xmlNewNs(root_node,
                BAD_CAST "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography",
                BAD_CAST "b");
xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root_node);
xmlNewChild(root_node, ns, BAD_CAST "Lcid", BAD_CAST "1042");
xmlDocPtr output = xsltApplyStylesheet(style, doc, 0);
mlChar* xmlData;
int size;
xmlDocDumpMemory(output, &xmlData, &size);
```

The expected result of the variable `xmlData` is "APA", but I got this result.

**My Result** 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii" standalone="yes"?>`

I want the same result of xsltproc. 
Can you figure out the problem of my code? 
It will be really helpful for your comment.
Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you post minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem. So provide a minimal but complete stylesheet for which the differences occur, describe the exact command line with which you call `xsltproc`. And you might want to add a tag for the C programming language as well and show the code that outputs the result of the XSLT transformation, i.e. that produces the "My Result" line you have shown.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you for your advice, I edited my question and gave some detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the result of an XSLT transformation isn't always a well-formed document and depends on `xsl:output`, you have to use one of the [`xsltSaveResultTo`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/html/libxslt-xsltutils.html#xsltSaveResultTo) functions to output the result.

Comment: I detailed the xsl code and `xsl:output` is like below `<xsl:output method="html" encoding="us-ascii"/>` would this be the problem?

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem using `xsltSaveResultToString` :)